# Oracle group by date, month and year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query to show me the count for each country group by single days such as 20160101.

How can I modify the below query so it can group by date, month and year?

Please note currently working on an Oracle database.

Many Thanks in advance.

```
Select count(1), country_of_sale, substr(datefield,1,8) AS datefield1
from table 
where country_of_sale IN (‘USA’,’EUROPE’,’ASIA’)
group by country_of_sale, substr(datefield,1,8)
order by substr(datefield,1,8)
```

Comment: Please show table definition, sample table data, and expected output.

Comment: Do you mean that you want all the dates individually ***and*** the sub-total for each month ***and*** the sub-total for each year?  As in `ROLLUP`?  To be sure, the best bet for you is to include both some example data and the results you expect to get from that sample data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `datefield` is a string, then just use `substr()`.  For year and month:

```
Select count(1), country_of_sale, substr(datefield, 1, 6) AS yyyymm
from table 
where country_of_sale IN ('USA', 'EUROPE', 'ASIA')
group by country_of_sale, substr(datefield, 1, 6)
order by substr(datefield, 1, 6);
```

If `datefield` is a date, then use `to_char()`:

```
Select count(1), country_of_sale, to_char(datefield, 'YYYY-MM') AS yyyymm
from table 
where country_of_sale IN ('USA', 'EUROPE', 'ASIA')
group by country_of_sale, to_char(datefield, 'YYYY-MM')
order by to_char(datefield, 'YYYY-MM');
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be smart to use dedicated functionality. Playing with strings will work, but can be slower and it also assumes things about your date/time formatting etc.

Oracle has a [TRUNC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) function, which "rounds down" a date to a day, month, etc.